# How to get the "fragment" part of an url in a nuxt middleware?

Tags: nuxt.js, url-fragment

I want to get the access_token in the url after a redirection from AWS COGNITO in a "implicit" oauth flow.
AWS Cognito redirect the browser to : https://mydomain/#access_token=xxxxx

I want to get the "access_token=xxxxx" part for storage, in a nuxt "middleware".

It doesn't seam to be in the "context.req" object. Where can I find it ?

Comment: It might be in `context.$route`.

Comment: Alas, context.$route is empty :(

Do I need to add a specific module or something ?

Comment: I tried a `console.warn(context)` and the access_token is nowhere ...

Comment: Are you using Nuxt in SSR mode? The fragment is never sent to server, this is something you can only do in the browser. It should be in the `$route.hash` property.

Comment: Damned ! Yes, I use SSR mode, I want to test this for a futur project which will need some SEO.  But after carefull consideration, it's true that I don't need the "connected" information server side ... "personnals informations" are not to be exposed to search engines or cached. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The **Implicit flow** doesn't return an authorization code like the **Authorization flow** does. You'll get the access token directly in the response body.

Here is a link with more info.

[Implicit Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/implicit)

Comment: What OP wrote was *I want to get the* **access_token**

Comment: As I said, the access token is in the body. Authorization codes come in the URI. Access tokens come in the response body.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/ -> read the bit what Amazon Cognito does in implicit flow and where it places the data. Then read what the OP asked and try to figure out why you're posting the wrong answer.

Comment: N.B is right, Cognito put the access token in the fragment part of the url, not in the body ... I can't find a way to change this behaviour ... So i'm stuck with this ...